# Integration as the limit of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

If $f$ is a regulated function, and $(\phi)_n$ is a sequence of step functions that converge uniformly to $f$, then we have defined $$\int_a^b f(x) dx := \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b (\phi)_n (x) dx \tag{1}$$ This has been given in my lectures as a definition and I am content with it. However, in school, it was defined that integration was the limit of a sum, namely, $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\delta x \rightarrow 0} \sum_{x=a}^b f(x) \delta x$$This definition is, of course, simpler to use and less complicated. It is given in my school books and a lot of online websites I see as the *definition* of the definite integral.

My question is, why is definition $(1)$ a better definition (or it is better)? Where is the second wrong and where does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition $(1)$ applies to a more general class of functions, namely the regulated functions, which can be written as the uniform limit of step functions. In particular, every continuous function defined on a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ can be written as such a limit, but there are regulated functions which are not continuous (any step function).

The second definition you offer is often phrased as
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx := \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n)\frac{b-a}{N} \tag{2}
$$
where $x_n$ is the midpoint of the $n$th interval having width $(b-a)/N$.
If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then this definition agrees with the definition of the Riemann integral. However, this definition is not valid for more general functions. Indeed, there are functions for which the limit in $(2)$ exists which are themselves not Riemann integrable.

For example, consider the function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x$ is rational,} \\
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$
For every $N$, the expression $\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x_n)\frac{1-0}{N} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N} = 1$, so the calculus-style limit $(2)$ exists and is equal to $1$, but $f$ is not Riemann integrable.
This shows how the calculus-style definition $(2)$ of the integral is inadequate.